# RT9080-33 LDO voltage regulator: enable chip with +5 V and GND

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, battery-charging, esp32

I'm designing a board based on an ESP32. I chose the [RT9080-33](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT9080/DS9080-05.pdf) as LDO voltage regulator.

I need to turn on the board in two different cases:

1. when the device is charging; in this case voltage is taken from the VBus of the USB, which via the voltage divider then arrives at the EN of the RT9080;
2. when the device is in use; in this case I can only give a GND consent: in this case I was thinking of using a P-channel MOSFET.

I have attached a schematic; can this be a good solution or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned how much is BATT+ voltage range. I assume it is say 4.2V typical.

1. In the case where device is not charging and when jumper is not connected to GND. Here you want EN to be 0V and disable the LDO. However, the bulk diode of the PMOS will conduct and pullup EN and hence the LDO will turn ON. You could normally solve it by flipping the source-drain connections of Q1 but since you also have a case where BATT+ is lower than EN (EN can go to 5V when charging & jumper disconnected), flipping Q1 does not help.
2. If USB VBUS is not present and you connect the jumper to GND, the PMOS will be ON and EN will be equal to BATT+. Now, EN is connected to +6.8v(MAX) via a 3.6k resistor and hence that voltage will go high eventhough USB VBUS is not present. Your system may false detect that USB VBUS is connected?

Here is a modification I propose to make scheme more robust
[image]

**Update:**
I simulated your **updated** scheme for the case when Vusb is disconnected and jumper is also disconnected. As you can see, EN goes to 3.45V instead of going to 0V. **So, your circuit does not work**.

[image]

If you swap the source-drain of M1 as shown, it will work in this case like shown below:

[image]

However, consider the case when USB cable is disconnected and the jumper is connected to GND. EN goes high and that pulls USB_VBUS to high. **You have to decide if this case be a problem** because your board may interpret it as USB connected if USB_VBUS goes high.

[image]

If you do not want this to happen, you have to add a diode as shown below and change R4 to 200 ohm. I don't see the need for the zener diode because the resistor divider (R3-R4) is enough. **Finally, be sure to simulate this for all scenarios and ensure it works for you.**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I would like to ask if a modification like in [this schematic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc5iQ.png) could work, as I'm trying to keep the number of components to a minimum. Theoretically Vusb should always be 5v, the voltage divider was for precautionary purposes, at the base of the circuit there is still a zener diode.

Comment: Add the updated schematic also in the question. You should not ask a new question in the comments. I have simulated the updated schematic and updated my answer

Comment: @sai - Hi, FYI the OP originally posted that comment as an answer. However, as it was clearly replying to you & was not an *answer*, I had 3 choices: (a) just delete it - that seemed excessively harsh; (b) move it into the question - that could cause problems, since it was aimed at your answer & extending a question after an answer has been posted is generally discouraged; (c) convert it to a comment on your answer, so that you could consider whether to treat it as an allowed request for clarification of your answer, or a disallowed new question.

Comment: (continued) I chose (c). It's OK for you to suggest (b) since it is only your answer which is affected by the question being updated. || I thought it might be helpful to explain how the situation started. I didn't see a choice which suited everyone :(

Comment: @SamGibson, I agree with your choice (c). No issues. Basically, the intention behind my last comment was to get the updated schematic also added to the question so that someone new reading my answer knows the context as to why I updated my answer. Otherwise, they will have to go through all the comments to understand why I updated my answer having proposed a solution already.